# How to set center image bigger than other images in horizontallistview when scrolled horizontally?

Tags: android, uiimageview, horizontalscrollview

Right now i am working on getting center image larger than other images in horizontallistview with scrolling option. I should set only 5 images atfirst in display with center image larger than others, when user scrolls the list, the image which gets in center should be greater than other images. I am stuck with this, can you guys help me to fix this problem.

XML

```
 <com.meetme.android.horizontallistview.HorizontalListView
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"/>
```

Here i goes with my code:

```
 imageListAdapter = new ImageListAdapter(getActivity(), imagesList);
    ViewUtils.show(imageGridView);
  imageGridView.setAdapter(imageListAdapter);

    imageGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position == 0){

                return;
            }
            icon= (ImageIcon) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        }
    });
```

Comment: share the code of your custom listview

Comment: above is my code where listview is set in imageGridView

Comment: you can show me any link or any sample ones related to my question

Answer (score 0):

Pass position of the view

```
public View updateSelectedView(int index){
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);
        View view = parent.getChildAt(index);
        view.getLayoutParams().height =view.getLayoutParams().width+20;
        view.getLayoutParams().width =view.getLayoutParams().width+20;
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: can you tel me how to show only 1st only 5 in view and then 5 by 5 on scroll.

Comment: i should show the center image bigger on loading in view not on selecting or touching an item in list